# Organizar uma matriz

Tags: javascript, array, node.js, matriz

Tenho um array contendo 16 objetos,cada objeto tem os atributos titulo,e definição. Preciso pôr dentro de cada objeto no atributo definição,as definições de acordo com o título.

```
    [{
    titulo: universo,
    definicao:["(Física) a totalidade da matéria e da energia existentes no espaço e no tempo, tudo o que existe, o todo"],
["todas as possibilidades em uma dada situação"]}]
```

Isso em todas as posições do meu array que contém os objetos,o problema é que recebo isso de um json que converti um xml,
para tanto,identifiquei um padrão onde contém os dados das definições,e criei um laço para pegar esses dados conforme essa parte do código

```
e.lists[0].forEach(function(a,b){
                // console.log(e.lists[0][b].text);
                    if(e.lists[0][b].text.match(/(^[0-9]{1,}\))|\#\s/)){
                       definicoes.push(e.lists[0][b].text);
                    }
                });
```

Porém não consegui criar uma lógica na qual inserisse os dados de forma que ficasse algo como:

```
[{
titulo:'titulo1'
definicao:['definicoes do titulo 1']},
{
titulo:'titulo2'
definicao:['definicoes do titulo 2']},
{
titulo:'titulo3'
definicao:['definicoes do titulo 3']},
{
titulo:'titulo4'
definicao:['definicoes do titulo 4']}]
```

Segue o código completo

```
var fs              = require("fs");
var parser          = require("fast-xml-parser");
var wtf             = require("wtf_wikipedia");
var textos          = [];
var objetos         = [];
var titulos         = [];
var definicoes      = [];




fs.readFile("wiktionary.part_11.xml",function(erro,xml){
     var ob         = parser.getTraversalObj(xml);
     var json       = parser.convertToJson(ob);
    // console.log(json.mediawiki.page[1].title);

    json.mediawiki.page.forEach(function(v,i){
        textos[i]   = wtf(v.revision.text).json();  
        titulos[i] = v.title;
    }); 
    textos.forEach(function(elem,indice){
        objetos[indice] = {};



        elem.sections.forEach(function(e,i){
            if(e.hasOwnProperty('paragraphs')){
                    e.paragraphs.forEach(function(ele,ind){
                         //console.log(ele,indice);

                         ele.sentences.forEach(function(d,info){

                            if(d.text.match(/(\# \w{2,})|(\[0-9]{1,})|(, \#)\) /i)){
                                console.log(d.text);
                            }
                         });
                    });
            }if(e.hasOwnProperty('templates')){
                    //console.log(textos[indice].sections[i].templates," templates",indice);
            }if(e.hasOwnProperty('lists')){

                e.lists[0].forEach(function(a,b){
                // console.log(e.lists[0][b].text);
                    if(e.lists[0][b].text.match(/(^[0-9]{1,}\))|\#\s/)){
                       definicoes.push(e.lists[0][b].text);
                    }
                });

            }
        });
 });
    objetos.forEach(function(ele,ind){
         ele[ind] = [];
         ele[ind].titulo        = titulos[ind];
         ele[ind].definicao     = [];

    });

    console.log(definicoes);


});
```

Answer (score 1):

Conseguir fazendo da seguinte maneira

```
var fs              = require("fs");
var parser          = require("fast-xml-parser");
var wtf             = require("wtf_wikipedia");
var textos          = [];
var objetos         = [];
var titulos         = [];
var definicoes      = [];




fs.readFile("wiktionary.part_11.xml",function(erro,xml){
     var ob         = parser.getTraversalObj(xml);
     var json       = parser.convertToJson(ob);
    // console.log(json.mediawiki.page[1].title);

    json.mediawiki.page.forEach(function(v,i){
        textos[i]   = wtf(v.revision.text).json();  
        titulos[i] = v.title;
    }); 
    textos.forEach(function(elem,indice){
        objetos[indice]         = {};
        definicoes[indice]      = [];


        elem.sections.forEach(function(e,i){
            if(e.hasOwnProperty('paragraphs')){
                    e.paragraphs.forEach(function(ele,ind){
                         //console.log(ele,indice);

                         ele.sentences.forEach(function(d,info){

                            if(d.text.match(/(\# \w{2,})|(\[0-9]{1,})|(, \#)\) /i)){
                               // console.log(d.text);
                            }
                         });
                    });
            }if(e.hasOwnProperty('templates')){
                    //console.log(textos[indice].sections[i].templates," templates",indice);
            }if(e.hasOwnProperty('lists')){

                e.lists[0].forEach(function(a,b){
                 //console.log(e.lists[0][b].text);
                    if(e.lists[0][b].text.match(/(^[0-9]{1,}\))|\#\s/)){
                       definicoes[indice].push(e.lists[0][b].text);
                    }
                });

            }
        });
 });
    objetos.forEach(function(ele,ind){
         ele[ind] = [];
         ele[ind].titulo        = titulos[ind];
         ele[ind].definicao     = [];
         ele[ind].definicao     = definicoes[ind];
         console.log(ele);

    });




});
```

E obtive o seguinte resultado:

```
{ '0':
   [ titulo: 'adulto',
     definicao: [ '1) diz-se do indivíduo que atingiu a maturidade do desenvolvimento fisiológico, intelectual e/ou emocional, em torno dos vinte anos de idade',
       '2) diz-se do indivíduo que atingiu a maioridade legal' ] ] }
{ '1':
   [ titulo: 'universo',
     definicao: [ '1)  a totalidade da matéria e da energia existentes no espaço e no tempo, tudo o que existe, o todo',
       '2) todas as possibilidades em uma dada situação',
       '3) o mundo, a Terra e a humanidade',
       '4)  o conjunto que engloba todos os elementos possíveis' ] ] }
{ '2':
   [ titulo: 'metafísica',
     definicao: [ '1) campo de estudo da filosofia que trata da natureza fundamental da realidade e do ser',
       '2) aquilo que está além da física, e por conseguinte, do mundo natural' ] ] }
{ '3':
   [ titulo: 'laranja',
     definicao: [ '1) que tem a cor da laranja, cor-de-laranja',
       '2) * A moça usava um vestido laranja.',
       '1) fruto cítrica da laranjeira, cuja cor característica é o laranja',
       '2) a cor da laranja, mistura do amarelo com o vermelho',
       '3)  intermediário cujo nome é usado em transações corruptas',
       '4) * Prenderam os laranjas, mas os ladrões continuam soltos.' ] ] }
{ '4':
   [ titulo: 'minuto',
     definicao: [ '1) período de tempo correspondente a 60 segundos',
       '2) unidade de medida angular correspondente a 1/60 de um grau' ] ] }
{ '5':
   [ titulo: 'homem',
     definicao: [ '1)  o mesmo que ser humano',
       '2)  a espécie Homo sapiens',
       '3)  indivíduo adulto do sexo masculino, varão da espécie Homo sapiens',
       '4)  um tipo de primata bípede e bímano da espécie Homo Sapiens' ] ] }
{ '6':
   [ titulo: 'elemento',
     definicao: [ '1) aquilo que é simples',
       '2) o que se pensa impossível de decompor',
       '3) o que é um componente de um todo',
       '4) matéria-prima',
       '5) meio preferido ou natural',
       '6) * Ele está no seu elemento.',
       '7)  substância simples com número atómico bem determinado',
       '8)  o fogo, a água, o ar e a terra, tidos em tempos como os constituintes do Universo',
       '9)  os conhecimentos tidos como básicos, introdutórios, essenciais de um ramo de saber',
       '10)  princípios; rudimentos',
       '11) pessoa',
       '12) ser, animal' ] ] }
{ '7':
   [ titulo: 'άνθρωπος',
     definicao: [ '1) ser humano; gente',
       '2) a espécie Homo sapiens sapiens',
       '3) indivíduo adulto do sexo masculino, varão, homem' ] ] }
{ '8': [ titulo: 'auxologia', definicao: [] ] }
{ '9': [ titulo: 'zigoto', definicao: [] ] }
{ '10': [ titulo: 'stomachache', definicao: [] ] }
{ '11':
   [ titulo: 'account',
     definicao: [ '1) conta',
       '2) * Take into account. &lt;small&gt;(Levar em conta)&lt;/small&gt;',
       '3) * Have into account. &lt;small&gt;(Ter em conta)&lt;/small&gt;',
       '4) relato' ] ] }
{ '12': [ titulo: 'adept', definicao: [] ] }
{ '13': [ titulo: 'adherent', definicao: [] ] }
{ '14':
   [ titulo: 'albeit',
     definicao: [ '1) se bem que, embora, muito embora, não obstante:' ] ] }
{ '15':
   [ titulo: 'aqui',
     definicao: [ '1) lugar onde situa-se o interlocutor',
       '2) * Sempre passamos por aqui.',
       '3) para o local onde situa-se o interlocutor',
       '4) * Venha aqui!' ] ] }
```